# How to clear browser cache using angular 7 in production

Tags: angular, caching

In my project I am using .net core and angular 7. I need to clear browser cache after every deployment.
ng build --prod --output-hashing=all, didn't work for me. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following tag in web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>      
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="0.00:01:00"/>//1 minutes
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```